# replacing the fonts with rereplace or replace

Tags: coldfusion

i need some help here with regards to `replace` or maybe `rereplace`

i am trying to replace the `font-family:anything` to `font-family:swiss7`

but if there is a value `font-family: BebasNeue`; i want that font untouched and do not add font-size, but add the font-size to the other fonts

I am following this tutorial but somehow its not matching as to what I need to achieve

> https://www.sitekickr.com/snippets/coldfusion/strip-css-styles

Comment: What have you tried so far? What kind of result have you gotten? What version of ColdFusion are you on? Can you put the CSS into a separate file? Etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update: well I thought the question was simpler. If you want to see my original answer just see the edit history for this post. This answer uses a similar principle though where you search for an item that you don't want removed and then push it back in with the replace.

```
<cfset teststr1 = "font-family: BebasNeue;" />
<cfset teststr2 = "font-family: Verdana" />
<cfset teststr3 = "font-family: BebasNeue; font-family: Times New Roman; color: red" />

<cfset search1 = "(font-family:\s*)((BebasNeue)|[\w ]+)(;)?" />
<cfset replace1 = "font-family: \3swiss7\4" />

<cfset search2 = "BebasNeueswiss7" />
<cfset replace2 = "BebasNeue" />

<cfoutput>
    <ol>
    <li>#replaceNoCase(reReplaceNoCase(teststr1, search1, replace1, "all"), search2, replace2, "all")#</li>
    <li>#replaceNoCase(reReplaceNoCase(teststr2, search1, replace1, "all"), search2, replace2, "all")#</li>
    <li>#replaceNoCase(reReplaceNoCase(teststr3, search1, replace1, "all"), search2, replace2, "all")#</li>
    </ol>
</cfoutput>
```

Result:

```
1. font-family: BebasNeue;
2. font-family: swiss7
3. font-family: BebasNeue; font-family: swiss7; color: red
```

So essentially you replace all font families with the chosen font type, in this case swiss7, but by including the group selector in the replace you leave the BebasNeue font in the string. An additional step then cleans up the combined font name left behind.

Comment: updated the answer to actually answer the question asked

Comment: seems to be fixing the issue, but it does not take into consideration if i need to add additional styles just only to that font-style where swiss7 is used, consider using font-size, font-weight

Comment: you probably figured it out already, but just need to adjusted the replace1 and search2 to add the additional code

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest a more maintainable approach:
`if !findNoCase( styleString, 'BebasNeue'){
styleString = REReplace(style, 'font-family:[^"|^;]*', "font-family:swiss7; font-size:12", "ALL");
}`

This should get you want you are after: leave it alone if it is BebasNeue, otherwise, change the font-family to swiss7 and add a font-size. But it is also not so complicated that a regex-newbie couldn't understand what is going on.

Comment: Downvoted because this doesn't take a mix of multiple `font-family` into account. The minimum approach would be a regex group capture and replace in each captured group after checking the font-family value.

Comment: @Alex I understand what you are saying, but the literal request was "font-family:anything to font-family:swiss7" unless "font-family: BebasNeue;". The ";" in the exception case indicates BebasNeue must be indicated as the sole font. A list of multiple fonts will be replaced with "swiss7" using my suggestion.

Comment: He is replacing the content of a whole css/html file. Check the link he mentioned. A simple replace/reReplace isn't sufficient here, because he needs a [regex matcher](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html).